# Kafka override log.retention.check.interval.ms for topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Basically the title. I was trying to find how to override property `log.retention.check.interval.ms` from CLI for some particular topic, but didn't succeed.

Is there is an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_log.retention.check.interval.ms), this field is present only at the broker config, so you cannot set a different value for each independent topic. I could not find any similar property in the [topic config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs)